# SUM on each line in a SELECT statement

Tags: php, sql, select, join, sum

**I have a problem with a join statement with a SUM on a field.
I have these two Tables:**

**Table 1 (parent): Trips**

- ID - int( 11 ) - Auto increment
- Maxspots - int( 11 )

**Table 2 (child): Bookings**

- ID - int( 11 ) - Auto increment
- FK_ID - int( 11 )
- Spots  - int( 11 )

I have the following code:

```
$SQL = "SELECT  ";
$SQL .= "SUM(Bookings.Spots) as SUMSPOT, Trips.ID, Bookings.FK_ID, Bookings.ID ";   
 $SQL .= "FROM Trips ";
 $SQL .= "INNER JOIN Bookings on Bookings.FK_ID = Trips.ID";

 $SQL_Query = mysql_query($SQL); 

 $tdOdd = 'style = "background-color: #FFFFFF;"';
 $tdEven = 'style = "background-color: #ced4ee;"';

 echo "<table>";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th>Trip nr</th>";
 echo "<th>Sum of spots</th>";
 echo "</tr>";

 $indx = 1; 
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($SQL_Query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

 $Tripnr = $row['FK_ID'];
 $Sumspots = $row['SUMSPOT'];

 if (($indx % 2) == 1) {$rowClass = $tdOdd; } else { $rowClass = $tdEven; }

 echo "<tr ".$rowClass.">";

 echo "<td>".$Tripnr."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$Sumspots."</td>";     

 echo "</tr>";

 $indx++;

}

 echo "</table>";   

 mysql_free_result($SQL_Query);
```

**Its returning only one Booking-line with the total sum of all spots (within the join). I need it to give me the sum of the Booking.Spots of each line. Help anyone?**

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text. Also show us your query stand-alone.

Comment: try to use `group by Spots` in your select query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `GROUP BY` for your non-aggregate fields.

```
$SQL = "SELECT  ";
$SQL .= "SUM(Bookings.Spots) as SUMSPOT, Trips.ID, Bookings.FK_ID, Bookings.ID ";   
$SQL .= "FROM Trips ";
$SQL .= "INNER JOIN Bookings on Bookings.FK_ID = Trips.ID";
$SQL .= "GROUP BY Trips.ID, Bookings.FK_ID, Bookings.ID";
```